# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php after renaming the project

Tags: laravel-5.3

Please follow the steps below  (For laravel 5.3)
**1-** I have laravel project named **projabc** and then I have created new folder with name **projxyz** and copied the contents of **projabc** into it, after that I have run the command in **projxyz**

```
php artisan app:name projxyz
```

It shows the message

```
Application namespace set!
```

**2-** Created the alias in wamp apache alias directories

**3-** My routes other than home page (http://localhost/projxyz/) did not work

**4-** I have then executed other several commands like
php artisan route:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan cache:clear
composer dumpautoload

Still it throws the error **(NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php on line 161)** when I access my other routes like

```
Route::get('/Contact-Us',function(){
    return view('front.contact_us');
});
```

by calling http://localhost/projxyz/Contact-Us

Comment: start the server with: php artisan projxyz/serve

Comment: php artisan serve,  run it on http://localhost:8000/ and it works fine but it is the temporary solution. Nightmare is the route did not even work with 
http://localhost/projxyz/public/Contact-Us/ .  Deploying it on shared hosting will create much problem. So need a permanent solution

Comment: Are you sure that you start the server inside htdocs/projxyz and do command php artisan serve??

Comment: I have wamp, project is in wamp/www/projxyz.  php artisan serve do work but I want to know why I cannot access  http://localhost/projxyz/public/Contact-Us  directly